# Yoast & W3 Cache cause Yoast XML sitemap to return a blank page?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the latest version of Yoast SEO Wordpress and W3 Total Cache. As soon as I activate the W3 Total Cache plugin the XML sitemap stops working in the Yoast SEO plugin???

```
Yoast SEO Wordpress Version: 1.4.19
W3 Total Cache Version: 0.9.3
```

Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet:http://alanbrandt.com/main-sitemap.xsl

Does anyone have any idea of how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer here after two hours of hair-pulling. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZxoXXanxWI

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue.

Trouble was coming from minification of js file in this main-sitemap.xsl by W3TC.
I just added "main-sitemap.xsl" in the "Never minify the following pages:" textbox on W3TC settings > Minify

Not a real fix indeed (there might be an issue in W3TC minification) but a nice workaround if you want to easily see the content of your sitemaps .xml files in a browser.